# Subtracting off Terms of a Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I hope this is clear.  Suppose i have a polynomial

$$p(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+c_1x+c_0$$

and I want to subtract off all terms of $p(x)$ whose powers are less than $k$.  So a new polynomial $q(x)$ is such that

$$q_k(x)=c_kx^k+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+...+c_1x+c_0$$.

with $k<n$.  Then $(p-q_k)(x)$ is some new polynomial

$$p(x)-q_k(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+c_{k+1}x^{k+1}$$

Here is my question.  Is there a way to write $p(x)-q_k(x)$ in terms of strictly the original polynomial $p(x)$?  Taking the $k$-th derivative would be one way and then multiplying the term by the appropriate power of $x$, but I was looking for someting simpler, strictly in terms of the original polynomial $p(x)$.  Perhaps its some shift in the argument, $p(x-\alpha)$, or maybe even a linear combination of $p(x)$.  Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\ q = (p\ {\rm mod}\ x^{\large k+1})\ $ thus  $\ p - q\, =\, p - (p\ {\rm mod}\ x^{\large k+1}) $

Comment: Is there any way to not use the modular notation?  For example, just subtracting off  $c_0$, $c_0=p(0)$, and so we have $p(x)-p(0)$...

Comment: @AveryJessup $\ p(0) = (p\ {\rm mod}\ x)\ $ so the above is in fact  a generalization of that.